# "!!" is no longer a remark in a batch file?

Tags: windows, command-line

Years ago, `!!` used to be shorthand for a remark. Now its producing errors:

```
> vs-build.cmd
>!! Run this from a Visual Studio command prompt !!
'!!' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
...
```

Trying to search for the string ***`"!!"`*** is producing less than desirable results because Google ignores those special characters.

Is there a way to tell `cmd.exe` to use `!!` as a remark? If so, how?

Comment: where did you get that `!!` remark? I can't find it anywhere

Comment: try // to comment it out.

Comment: To google try "double exclamation mark"

Comment: Another way is using a [symbol search engine](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4685615/995714)

Comment: AFAIK the only usage for a pair of exclamation marks in bat files are expanding variables `!like_this!`, and it's not a double `!`

Comment: !Variable! does not expand variables. I believe that you are thinking of %Variable%

Comment: `!var!` does expand: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205093/7552

Answer (score 5):

`!!` was never a comment command in Batch.  You are probably thinking of the double colon (`::`).

Having said that, using `::` instead of `Rem` is bad practice as it's an un-callable label, not a true analog to `Rem`.

More information is available at StackOverflow in this question:

- [Which comment style should I use in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12407800/which-comment-style-should-i-use-in-batch-files)

Comment: Thanks Techie007. *"!! was never a comment command in Batch"* - I'm either crazy (could well be), or I need to do some more research on it (my memory is not what it used to be). I recall using `!!` for a REMark. What I'm wondering is if its the wrong dev environment. As a matter of fact, I recall the `!!` being changed to `REM` when performing a `CTRL+S` (Save), and wondering how I could persist it since I liked the way it balanced.

Comment: @jww If you can find the reference I'd be happy to see it. :)

Comment: Sorry, but what is an un-callable lable? I've only used "::" for comments.

Comment: @VitaminYes It's a label (`:Label`) that you can't call with a Goto.  I couldn't come up with a better term. :)

Answer (score 0):

!! is a comment?
News to me.
Try ::
*THAT* has served as a "comment" for a long time.
Actually, it wasn't necessarily meant as a comment: it was designed to be a "label" to "goto", since it starts with a colon, a double-colon happens to be a label that cannot be reached via the "goto" command.  As a label, the rest of the line isn't parsed.  So the end result is, effectively, a comment.